# Is there a generic way to lookup what a hotkey/shortcut does under current user prefs?

Tags: modeling

Example: today I worked through a tutorial where the person running the tutorial casually said "And now we'll double tap R..."

This is easy enough to follow, behaved as expected, and I can see that the behavior is different from just hitting R once and rotating normally. I am not sure what the nature of this difference is, though, and would like to be able to look up in my Blender interface: what action/behavior is currently mapped to the key combination "double-tap R"?

Is there a generic way of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.

You can go to `Setting > Keymap`, here is all the input event user does.

And up there is a search bar. With *Key-Binding* search method selected, you can search your short cut by key.

[image: Key]

If you are using 2.79b for an old favor. The same panel is in `user preference > Input`.

And the sequence of what you tap when operator is running (the second *R*) is inside the modal group keymap, you need to expand the action group to see it.

[image: Modal keymap]

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty much exactly what I was hoping for.

One question, though: I don't see any indication of 'double-tapping' a key on any of the results? e.g. double-tap R as in the tutorial I referenced, or double-tap G to edge-drag, etc. Any idea how that is represented in this panel, if it is?

Comment: That is defined inside the operator. You could go to that operator and expand the group. There will be a **_something_ modal map**, that is the content you press the second key. I will edit the answer for the picture.